# Java - Read numbers from a txt file and write them into a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

My goal is to read data from a txt file, and place them into a 2d array. my code thats giving me issues is:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));

    //save the number of vertex's
    vCount = input.nextInt();

    //create a 2d array
    Integer[][] adjList = new Integer[vCount][vCount];

    String line;
    String [] arrLn;

    for (int i = 0; i < vCount; i++) {

        line = input.nextLine(); //the value of 'line' never changes
        arrLn = line.split(" ");

        for (int j = 0; j < vCount; j++) {
            adjList[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(arrLn[j]); //errors list problem is here
        }
    }
```

sample txt file is this:

```
5
1 2 3 4
2 3
3 1 2
4 1 4
5 2 4
```

Where the first row is the number of verteces and the rest of the rows are the data to be inserted into the array. They need to be inserted so that each row in the txt file stays in its own row in the array (ie: elements in array row 1 cant equal '1,2,3,4,2,3', but rather '1,2,3,4'.

I cannot for the life of me understand why the line variable does not actually read the line. And Im getting no errors in the code, just when I run it.

Error recieved:

```
run:
Enter the File Name
C:\Users\YAZAN\Desktop\test.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at dbsearchs.Graph.runBFS(Graph.java:38)
at dbsearchs.Driver.main(Driver.java:24)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 26 seconds)
```

Comment: This is creepingly similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797174/how-do-i-add-a-line-from-a-file-into-an-array?noredirect=1 . Are you two working on the same schoolproject or somthing? asking very similar questions at pretty much the same time.

Comment: "And Im getting no errors in the code, just when compiling." Are you sure you mean `just when compiling`?

Comment: I don't believe we are. No one in my class goes by the name of Dreike.

Comment: So many downvotes but not a single answer...

Comment: At first I downvoted your question, but I changed my mind and actually upvoted instead becase I think you describe the problem quite well -- at least after your edit.

Comment: @Luiggi - The error message says why: line is a an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, are you really sure that the value of `line` never changes?

Secondly, there might be a problem because you call first input.nextInt() and then input.nextLine(). Try instead with performing input.nextLine() instead of nextInt() and get your number from that line. Currently, your first call to input.nextLine() is most likely giving you what's left of the first line -- nothing.

Thirdly, I believe you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception once the NumberFormatException is fixed when you run the program. In your second loop, don't loop until vCount but loop until arrLn.length instead.

Comment: My guess is that the first call to nextLine is giving @yazan what's left of the first line, precisely because ofthe use of nextInt.

Comment: @ScottHunter I had the same feeling, that's why I'm suggesting this change.

Comment: I am pretty sure 'line' didn't change. I had debug mode on and the value for 'line' was "", It may have picked up the whitespace like you said. I fixed it and it worked like you said as well. Thank you.

Comment: @yazan The value of line did change, because it was not initialized at first. Not being initialized and containing an empty string is not the same thing. Glad my answer helped you.

Comment: @ Simon, but doesn't not being initialized and being empty mean the same?

Comment: @yazan Not initialized = Not having a value. Containing an empty string = Having a value, the value is: An empty string.

Comment: So thats where the null value for an object comes in?

Comment: @yazan In one way `null` is the same as "not initialized" but in one way it's different. For example, try `String abc; if (abc == null)` and you will get a compile error, because abc is not initialized. `null` is "a value reserved for indicating that the pointer does not refer to a valid object" (Thank you Wikipedia).

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense now. I appreciate it